# Repulsive Force between two cuboidal magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I have 2 cuboidal permanent magnets(same grade) which are kept a small distance apart. They are kept such that they will repel each other. How do I calculate the force of repulsion between them?
I know the properties of the magnets and the distance of separation between them is known and to be kept fixed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors that can influence the magnetic fields of the magnets. Measuring the repulsion force can be difficult.
There is a great resource for neodymium magnets on K&J Magnetics website. Here is a link to the resource that might help you with this, https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.repel.asp?calcType=block.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The thing is i had obtained the repulsive force from the calculator that you had mentioned and was trying to verify the same analytically using Equivalent Magnetic charge theory, but i got erratic values which were not even close to the values shown in the calculator. I believe that i've done some mistake in modeling the equation. Is there any other approach besides Charge Theory to calculate it analytically.

Comment: I have used a program called FEMM to model magnets and magnetic fields. This is an analytical way to examine this but it isn't a system that you can write out by hand. A point charge isn't exactly similar to a magnet like this since the size of the magnet is going to have an influence on the shape of the field that it creates. Also the way that the field is on the surface of the magnet isn't completely uniform across the face as well.